# Hashmap get tag crashes

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, hashmap

I have an **array named checkBox** that contains checkboxes items in my xml. I also have a **HashMap** that stores the value of each of the checkboxes in Double.

Now the problem is when I try to getTag() inside the loop that checks the selected checkboxes by user, it crashes without error shown. I do not understand what went wrong.

```
        double priceSum= 0.0;
    for (CheckBox cb:checkBoxes) {

        cb.setEnabled(true);

        if (cb.isChecked()) {
            count++;
            toppingsSelection.add(cb); //adding selected items into arrayList

        }

    }

    for (CheckBox items: toppingsSelection) {

        text = text + items.getText().toString()+ ", ";

        priceSum += hashMap.get(items.getTag()); //THIS CAUSES CRASHING
    }

    toppings.setText(text); displaying texts of checkboxes checked
    price.setText(Double.toString(priceSum));
```

This is my hashmap:

```
    hashMap.put("chkCheese", 2.50);
    hashMap.put("chkPep", 3.50);
    hashMap.put("chkChick", 2.00);
    hashMap.put("chkBeef", 4.00);
    hashMap.put("chkBlackOlives", 2.00);
    hashMap.put("chkPine", 1.00);
    hashMap.put("chkMushroom", 1.00);
```

Comment: post your logcat.

Comment: Probably you didn't set tag on each CheckBox

Answer (score 0):

It was a rookie mistake, I have to set tags to my checkboxes in my XML file